# If a structure models $\alpha \vee \beta$ for either one a sentence, then it models $\alpha$ or it models $\beta$

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, model-theory

The first part of my question is:

Prove that if $\alpha$ or $\beta$ is a sentence, that $\mathfrak{A} \vDash (\alpha \vee \beta) \Rightarrow (\mathfrak{A} \vDash \alpha $ or $\mathfrak{A} \vDash \beta)$.

I can see how this would be easy to prove if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ we're both sentences from the definitions and the fact that if a sentence is satisfied with one variable assignment function, then it is satisfied for them all. But I cant seem to figure out **how to do it in the case where only one of $\alpha$ or $\beta$ is a sentence?**

Then my other question would be, how/why this can fail when $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are not sentences? Does it rely on certain aspects of the language? For instance if I had a very simple language with just one relation symbol, what would a counter example be, or would one even exist?

Comment: I would say that $\mathfrak{A}\models \alpha$ is only even defined if $\alpha$ is a sentence (or a formula where elements of $\mathfrak{A}$ have been substituted for every free variable, so a sentence over the enlarged language with a constant symbol for each element of $\mathfrak{A}$).  What is your definition of it if $\alpha$ is not a sentence?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the formal definition of *satisfaction* of a formula :

> $\mathfrak A \vDash \varphi [s]$.

If $\varphi$ is a *sentence*, then either $\mathfrak A$ satisfies $\varphi$ with every function $s$ from $\text {Var}$ into $|\mathfrak A|$, or $\mathfrak A$ does not satisfy $\varphi$ with any such function.

What is the definition of $\mathfrak A \vDash \alpha$ when $\alpha$ has a free variable $x$ ? We may adopt the convention that $\mathfrak A \vDash \alpha$ iff $\mathfrak A \vDash \forall x \alpha$.

In this case, the question amounts to :

> Prove that if $\alpha$ or $\beta$ is a sentence, that $\mathfrak{A} \vDash \forall x \ (\alpha \vee \beta) \Rightarrow (\mathfrak{A} \vDash \forall x \alpha $ or $\mathfrak{A} \vDash \forall x \beta)$.

If neither $\alpha$ nor $\beta$ are *sentences*, the property does not hold : consider the structure $\mathbb N$ and the formula $\forall x (\text {Even}(x) \lor \text {Odd}(x))$.

---

Let assume that $\alpha$ is a sentence and consider $\mathfrak A$ whatever such that $\mathfrak{A} \vDash \alpha \vee \beta$, i.e. $\mathfrak{A} \vDash \forall x \ (\alpha \vee \beta)$.

If $\alpha$ holds in $\mathfrak A$, it's done.

So, consider the case : $\mathfrak{A} \nvDash \alpha$. This means that $\alpha \lor \beta$ must be satisfied by every $s$, and due to the fact that $s$ does not satisfies $\alpha$, we have $\mathfrak A \vDash \beta[s]$, for every $s$.